# how to do a swipeable on Material3 compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

On the Material and Material2 *Compose* there was a **SwipeableState** and a *swipeable* option on the Modifier. But in Material3 this doesn't exist, at all. So how do you create a Swipeable in Material3? If anyone knows please share.

Answer (score 9):

[This `kotlinlang` slack](https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/505431/I-m-using-compose-material-3-1-0-0-alpha13-and-found-that-th) includes a link to [issue 229839039](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229839039), which is about making `SwipeableState` public in the Material3 Compose library and a discussion about what you should be doing:

> We are currently evaluating the API surface we want to offer for Swipeable, including a possible Foundation API. As there are quite a few issues with Swipeable, we haven't made it public in M3 yet.
>
> Comment #2 on the issue linked above gives you the full explanation and recommendations if you need something to give to your leads
>
> For the time being, we recommend forking Swipeable if you need it in M3!

So you can either also include the Material2 Compose library and use its `Swipeable` or fork it entirely (i.e., copy/paste the code into your project) and use it directly.

Answer (score 4):

The successor of Swipeable is AnchoredDraggable with `AnchoredDraggableState` and `Modifier.anchoredDraggable`. They were introduced in Compose-Foundation 1.6.0-alpha01 and are still experimental. Here is the migration guide (that unfortunately misses a complete example): https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/pointer-input/migrate-swipeable

Comment: There is a poorly described example in https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2594266/26/compose/foundation/foundation/samples/src/main/java/androidx/compose/foundation/samples/AnchoredDraggableSample.kt