# Jetpack compose rememberSwipeableState is internal

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

i want to create a swipable component using jetpack compose and as the document [Gestures | JetpackCompose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures#swiping) I should use `rememberSwipeableState`.
but when I want to use it I face this error:

```
Cannot access 'rememberSwipeableState': it is internal in 'androidx.compose.material3'
```

what should I do?

Comment: Similar post that links to a filed issue about material3's swipeable API
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72850990/how-to-do-a-swipeable-on-material3-compose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is already being tracked [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229839039), issue in Material3 Compose. Alternatively as per their recommendation

> For the time being, we recommend forking Swipeable if you need it in
> M3!

you can use Material2 Compose `Swipeable` and fork it.